# Error in Importing WSO2 EMM

Tags: maven, wso2

I've downloaded WSO2 developer studio from the below link:

http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/

Now I'm trying to import WSO2 EMM source code and I'm getting below same errors for 2 POM.xml files.

I'm getting below errors:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find
>   org.wso2.carbon:identity:pom:4.2.0 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Relative Path is

```
<relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by miss pom file. Which project do you import?

If you can run mvn eclipse:eclipse, then import into eclipse. This is what I did.